# Copying one string from one place to another on a sign

Tags: java, bukkit

How would I copy what is entered in line 1 of the sign? it should either be open or closed I want to move it to line 3. the lines start from 0 and go to 3. so if someone entered open on the second line then it would show up as open on the last line

```
package me.mcmatt.shops;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.Sound;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.block.Sign;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.block.SignChangeEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;

public class Signs implements Listener {


  @
  EventHandler
  public void onSignChange(SignChangeEvent e) {
    if (e.getLine(0).equalsIgnoreCase("[shop]")) {
      Block attached = e.getBlock().getRelative(0, -1, 0);
      String name = e.getPlayer().getDisplayName();
      if (!(attached.getType() == Material.CHEST))
        e.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please place the shop on a chest!");
      else {
        if (!e.getPlayer().hasPermission("shops.create"))
          e.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You don't have permission to create a shop! (shops.create)");
        else {
          if (!Arrays.asList("open", "closed").contains(e.getLine(1).toLowerCase())) {
            e.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You must specify if the shop is open or closed on the second line!");
          } else {
            Sign o = (Sign) e.getBlock().getState();
            e.setLine(0, "§9[Shop]");
            e.setLine(1, "§4" + name + "'s");
            e.setLine(2, "§4Shop");
            e.setLine(3, o.getLine(1));
            e.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Shop Created!");
            e.getPlayer().playSound(e.getPlayer().getLocation(), Sound.LEVEL_UP, 10, 10);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @
  EventHandler
  public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
    if (e.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK)) {
      Player p = e.getPlayer();
      Block b = e.getClickedBlock();
      Material m = b.getType();
      if (!(m == Material.SIGN_POST)) {
        return;
      } else {
        Sign sign = (Sign) e.getClickedBlock().getState();
        if ((sign.getLine(0).equalsIgnoreCase("§9[Shop]"))) {
          p.sendMessage("I right clicked the sign!");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the lines being set, and set line 3 with the appropriate value:

```
//on SignChangeEvent 'event'
event.setLine(3, event.getLine(1));
```

As you've done in your question, so check the logic of the rest of your code to make sure that it will execute correctly.

Personally I wouldn't try to set someone's input as an output directly, rather I would take what they have given me and then use it accordingly:

```
boolean closed = true;
if ("open".equalsIgnoreCase(event.getLine(1)) {
    closed = false;
}
String lineThree = closed ? "Closed" : "Open";
```